# LINQ To SQL Alias shown in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How would I show a linq to SQL Alias value in a MVC 5 RAZOR View. This is the code that I have in my controller:

```
    var Query = (from c in db.Contractors
                 join cmb in db.ContractorManagedBies on c.ManagedBy equals cmb.ManagedBy
                 join dc in db.DCLocMappings on c.LocationID equals dc.LocationID
                 join at in db.AccountTitles on c.AccountTitleID equals at.AccountTitleID
                 let Fullname = cmb.ManagerFirstName + ' ' + cmb.ManagerLastName
                 where dc.DeliveryCenter == location
                 select new { cmb.ManagedBy, Fullname}).ToList();
```

When I go to my RAZOR View, I have no idea how to get the Fullname value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a ViewModel with those fields... so your view is strongly typed... That way your view has the @model List<YourViewModel>... is the cleanest way. In the query you user select new YourViewModel { xxxx }

Comment: I was able to get so far as the view model and modifying the select without error, but the Fullname object is not appearing. I am not sure what the issue is. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify the above, you need to define an object in your model that holds the results of your select, and instead of selecting an anonymous object in your query, select your results into your custom object.

Comment: I believe I did this by adding: 

  select new ManagedByFields
     { Fullname = cmb.ManagerFirstName + ' ' + cmb.ManagerLastName                                           }; to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Model

```
public class Contractor()
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
    public string ManagedBy {get;set;}
}
```

View Model Class

```
public class ContractorViewModel()
{
    public List<Contractor> Contractors {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Contractors()
{
    var viewModel = new ContractorViewModel();
    var query = (from c in db.Contractors
                 join cmb in db.ContractorManagedBies on c.ManagedBy equals cmb.ManagedBy
                 join dc in db.DCLocMappings on c.LocationID equals dc.LocationID
                 join at in db.AccountTitles on c.AccountTitleID equals at.AccountTitleID
                 where dc.DeliveryCenter == location
                 select new { cmb.ManagedBy, cmb.ManagerFirstName, cmb.ManagerLastName}).ToList().Select(x => new Contractor {
                 FullName = x.ManagerFirstName + ' ' + x.ManagerLastName,
                 ManagedBy = x.ManagedBy
                 }).ToList();

    viewModel.Contractors = query;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
@foreach(var contractor in Model.Contractors)
{
    <p>@contractor.FullName</p>
    <p>@contractor.ManagedBy</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there but FullName object is still not recognized.  The error message shows because it is also looking for FullName in the Contractor dataset when in fact it is a function of another dataset based on the join clause. The name of the other dataset is ContractorManagedBy. What I am attempting to do is take a join returning an int value for a row and the do another linq query to find the value in the join and then combine the first and last name of that table based on that additional join and show it as part of the original query

Comment: So when placing a break point on query and enumerating the list, you don't see anything or is FullName null?

Comment: Well, the message that I get is ...does not contain a definition for 'FullName' so it doesn't even get to compile.

Comment: Do you get that message in the view or controller?

Comment: I get that message in the controller